# PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Tags: apt, sudo, pdf, libraries, poppler

Currently I am trying to use pdfinfo for extracting the content in the pdf files.

I have installed poppler-utils in local using

```
!sudo apt-get install -y poppler-utils
```

and it worked, Now I am running the same code in Databricks jupyter notebook, for the this command have worked perfectly and when I check `which pdfinfo` it gave me a path.

After that when I am running the command its not installing and giving an error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpoppler118 poppler-data
Suggested packages:
  ghostscript fonts-japanese-mincho | fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-japanese-gothic | fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
  fonts-arphic-uming fonts-nanum
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpoppler118 poppler-data poppler-utils
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,263 kB/3,434 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpoppler118 amd64 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 poppler-utils amd64 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpoppler118 amd64 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 poppler-utils amd64 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package poppler-data.
(Reading database ... 98324 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../poppler-data_0.4.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking poppler-data (0.4.11-1) ...
Setting up poppler-data (0.4.11-1) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5) ...
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler118_22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/poppler-utils_22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
```

I have tried multiple ways but same situation.

```
!apt install poppler-utils -y
!sudo apt-get install -y poppler-utils
!sudo apt-get install -y poppler-utils --fix-missing
```

Can anyone help me with this?!

Comment: Is your package cache up to date?  It looks like you might not have run `apt-get update` for a while.

Comment: I am updating, even though it's giving the same error!